# Having trouble getting the final value in my fetch().then sequence being the final return value of my function

Tags: javascript, get, request, fetch

**This code is working perfectly as the url value expected is coming through but the final return value of the entire function is not returning url?**

getPreviewUrl(trackId) {
            console.log(trackId);

```
      return  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${trackId}`,{
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${usersAccessToken}`

            }
        }).then(response => {
            let jsonResponse = response.json();
            console.log(jsonResponse);
            return jsonResponse;


        }).then(jsonResponse => {


            console.log(jsonResponse.preview_url);
            let url = jsonResponse.preview_url;

            return url;

        });



    }
```

Comment: Not clear what the problem is but does `getPreviewUrl(trackId).then(url=>console.log('got url:',url))` work? This because if `return fetch....` is returned in `getPreviewUrl` then `getPreviewUrl` returns a promise.

Comment: it should be so simple...I just want the value of url to be the final return value of the function but instead its an object?

Comment: Then you don't understand how JavaScript solved asynchronious handling with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Short version: you want to return a value from the function, a function returns a value immediately but the value you want to return is not immediately available. It may never be available if it fails to fetch.

Comment: It did fetch and the url is coming back as expected and the value is stored in the variable url as expected. how do I get that value to be the final return value of the getPreviewUrl() method?

Comment: so is it not possible to get that value out of the function thats the whole point

Comment: `do I get that value to be the final return value of the getPreviewUrl() method?` Translated: `How do I immediately return a value that may be available later?`. Answer: you return a promise and with that returned promise you have to use `.then(result=>...here you have result`. Once you understand that it should be easier to use promises.

Comment: i got you now thankyou!